# React/Redux clear form elements values after submit

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have problems with clearing values from input and select form elements in `react form` after successful submit through axios library. Just want to mention that i do not use `redux-form`.

I don't know if I am on the right track here, this is my workflow by far: I wrote a form with `react-bootstrap`, give every input and select value through props and I access and update the state through these props. I have wrote actions and reducers for updating input values, and one action is dispatched in my component, but the second action and the reducer that is supposed to clear values after submit doesn't work as expected. This is the main problem, I'm not sure if I dispatch FORM_RESET action form in the right place, because I call it in the action that is responsible for posting data to server, and on success callback I dispatch FORM_RESET.

Below is the code relevant for this problem.

/* actionRegister.js */

```
let _registerUserFailure = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: types.SAVE_USER_FAILURE,
        payload
    };
};
let _registerUserSuccess = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: types.SAVE_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload,
        is_Active: 0,
        isLoading:true
    };
};

let _hideNotification = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: types.HIDE_NOTIFICATION,
        payload: ''
    };
};

//asynchronous helpers
export function registerUser({ //use redux-thunk for asynchronous dispatch
    timezone,
    password,
    passwordConfirmation,
    email,
    name
}) {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.all([axios.post('/auth/signup', {
                    timezone,
                    password,
                    passwordConfirmation,
                    email,
                    name,
                    is_Active: 0
                })
                // axios.post('/send', {email})
            ])
            .then(axios.spread(res => {
                dispatch(_registerUserSuccess(res.data.message));
                dispatch(formReset()); //here I dispatch clearing form data
                setTimeout(() => {
                    dispatch(_hideNotification(res.data.message));
                }, 10000);
            }))
            .catch(res => {
                dispatch(_registerUserFailure(res.data.message)); //BE validation and passport error message
                setTimeout(() => {
                    dispatch(_hideNotification(res.data.message));
                }, 10000);
            });
    };
}
```

/* actionForm.js */

```
//synchronous action creators
export function formUpdate(name, value)  {
    return {
        type: types.FORM_UPDATE_VALUE,
        name, //shorthand from name:name introduced in ES2016
        value
    };
}
export function formReset() {
  return {
    type: types.FORM_RESET
  };
}
```

/* reducerRegister.js */

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error:{},
  is_Active:false,
  isLoading:false
};
const reducerSignup = (state = INITIAL_STATE , action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.SAVE_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, is_Active:false, isLoading: true, error: { register: action.payload }};
      case types.SAVE_USER_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, error: { register: action.payload }};
      case types.HIDE_NOTIFICATION:
      return { ...state , error:{} };
   }
      return state;
};
export default reducerSignup;
```

/* reducerForm.js */

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    values: {}
};
const reducerUpdate = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.FORM_UPDATE_VALUE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                values: Object.assign({}, state.values, {
                    [action.name]: action.value,
                })
            });
        case types.FORM_RESET:
        return INITIAL_STATE;
        //here I need isLoading value from reducerRegister.js
    }
    return state;
};
export default reducerUpdate;
```

/* SignupForm.js */

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import map from 'lodash/map';
import timezones from '../../data/timezones';
import styles from '../formElements/formElements.scss';
import {registerUser}  from '../../actions/actionRegister';
import {formUpdate}   from '../../actions/actionForm';
import FieldGroup from '../formElements/FieldGroup';
import { Form, FormControl, Col, Checkbox, Button, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';


// {... props} passing large number of props wrap in object with spread notation
class SignupForm extends Component { //if component have state it needs to be class
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         errors: { //this errors are irrelevant for now
           name:'',
           email: '',
           password: '',
           passwordConfirmation:'',
           timezone:''
         },
       };
    }
    onChange = (event, index, value) => {
       this.props.onChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);
    };
    onSave = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSave(this.props.values);
    }
    render() {
      let isLoading = this.props.isLoading;
        return (
                    // this.props.handleSubmit is created by reduxForm()
         // if the form is valid, it will call this.props.onSubmit
         <Form onSubmit={this.onSave} horizontal>
   <FieldGroup
     id="formControlsName"
     type="text"
     label="Name"
     name="name"
     placeholder="Enter Name"
     value={this.props.values[name]}
     onChange={this.onChange}
     help={this.state.errors.name}
   />
   <FieldGroup
     id="formControlsEmail"
     type="text"
     label="Email"
     name="email"
     placeholder="Enter Email"
     value={this.props.values[name]}
     onChange={this.onChange}
     help={this.state.errors.email}
   />
   <FieldGroup
     id="formControlsPassword"
     type="password"
     label="Password"
     name="password"
     placeholder="Enter Password"
     value={this.props.values[name]}
     onChange={this.onChange}
     help={this.state.errors.password}
   />
   <FieldGroup
     id="formControlsPasswordConfirmation"
     type="password"
     label="Password Confirmation"
     name="passwordConfirmation"
     placeholder="Enter Password"
     value={this.props.values[name]}
     onChange={this.onChange}
     help={this.state.errors.passwordConfirmation}
   />
   <FieldGroup
     id="formControlsTimezone"
     label="Time Zone"
     name="timezone"
     placeholder="Select Time Zone"
     componentClass="select"
     defaultValue="Select Your Timezone"
     value={this.props.values[name]}
     onChange={this.onChange}
     help={this.state.errors.timezone}
   >
     <option value="Select Your Timezone">Select Your Timezone</option>
       {
        map(timezones, (key, value) =>
         <option  key={key} value={key}>{value}</option>)
       }
     </FieldGroup>
   <FormGroup>
      <Col smOffset={4} sm={8}>
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Col>
    </FormGroup>
   <FormGroup>
    <Col smOffset={4} sm={8}>
     <Button type="submit"  disabled={isLoading}
       onClick={!isLoading ? isLoading : null}
     >
     { isLoading ? 'Creating...' : 'Create New Account'}
       </Button>
   </Col>
       </FormGroup>
         {this.props.errorMessage && this.props.errorMessage.register &&
          <div className="error-container">{this.props.errorMessage.register}</div>}
   </Form>
             //this.setState({ disabled: true });
            //this.props.errorMessage.register == this.props = {errorMessage :{ register: ''}}
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.signup.error,
    isLoading: state.signup.isLoading,
    values: state.form.values

    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
   onSave: (values) => dispatch(registerUser(values)),
   onChange: (name, value) => dispatch(formUpdate(name, value))
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignupForm)
```

;

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `redux-form` :-) You're on the right path and you're calling `FORM_RESET` action in the right place.

**Couple of things:**

- are you sure you are importing `formReset` in `actionRegister.js`?
- in `reducerForm` I would suggest to still return new state here:

  `case types.FORM_RESET:
     return { ...INITIAL_STATE }; // or Object.assign({}, INITIAL_STATE)`

And btw. why are you setting `isLoading: true` on success? I would suggest to create 3 actions instead of 2:

- `SAVE_USER_START` (which you `dispatch` before sending a request),
  set `isLoading` to `true`,
- `SAVE_USER_SUCCESS` - set `isLoading` to `false`
- `SAVE_USER_FAILURE` - set `isLoading` to `false`

Comment: Check out his question "Just want to mention that i do not use redux-form". And the best answer to his question is not "use redux-form instead"...

Comment: Thanks a lot @szymomn, i'll give it a try with your suggestion

Comment: @WitVault the redux-form import is left over form previous attempt, i don't use it any more, anyway thanks for noticing that, will delete that import

Comment: Yeah better remove that to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into `redux-form` library. It provides configuration option to clear fields after submit out of the box.